# Assigning Range array from a returning function

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to have an array of ranges to create charts from them.

Here's how I had it:

```
Dim infoR As Range
Dim aRng() As Range
Dim numLvls As Integer

Set infoR = Range("H1:H100");

numLvls = getLevels()

Set aRng() = getOnlyNumericCellToArrayRanges(infoR, numLvls)
```

The function is this:

```
Function getOnlyNumericCellsRangesArrays(ByVal actRange As Range, ByVal numLvls As Integer) As Range()

    Dim aRng() As Range
    Redim aRng(0 To numLvls - 1)

    'Some code

    Set getOnlyNumericCellToArrayRanges = aRng()

End Function
```

I've seen several arrays examples over the internet and they use variant as a data type for that means but it doesn't compile like that too.

I've found that works with some changes:

```
Dim aRng

'Some code

aRng = getOnlyNumericCellToArrayRanges(infoR)
```

I think passing the array by reference could work, however I want to know if there is a way to make the array declaration and assignment to Range data type explicitly from the beginning.

Or how can I cast the result array back into a Range array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is not an object (even when it's an array of objects), so you don't need `Set` here...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arrRng() As Range, x As Long

    arrRng = GetRangeArray()
    For x = LBound(arrRng) To UBound(arrRng)
        Debug.Print arrRng(x).Address()
    Next x

End Sub


Function GetRangeArray() As Range()

    Dim arrRng() As Range

    ReDim arrRng(1 To 3)
    Set arrRng(1) = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set arrRng(2) = ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
    Set arrRng(3) = ActiveSheet.Range("A5")

    GetRangeArray = arrRng
End Function
```

Comment: Great, it worked as you said. Thanks. Come to my mind lots of other questions about it I have now. Can you give me some resources or some good book where I can go to?

Comment: First two books here are very good resources: http://www.amazon.com/Best-Excel-VBA-Books/lm/3P9T4WT9MA29P